# Subclassing LINQ to SQL Data Entities - Bad Idea or Missing Something?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, subclass

I would like to be able to subclass automatically generated LINQ to SQL Data Classes and save changes to said objects.

For example, if I have a table `Client` in my database, I can create `ClientBO` that extends class `Client`, and adds behaviors like `GenerateInvoice()` or whatever. Everything works fine until I want to update values in a subclass or insert a new record. Such changes are (predictably?) discarded. Is there something I'm missing, or am I violating a LINQ to SQL or OO principle by creating these subclasses in the first place?

Following are simplified examples of my code:

```
public class ClientBO : Client
{
    public ClientBO( Client source ) : base()
    {
        FirstName = source.FirstName;
        Lastname = source.LastName;
        // ... etc ...
    }
}

List<ClientBO> clientList = 
    ( from client in DatabaseContext.Clients select new ClientBO( client ) ).ToList();

clientList[ someIndex ].SomeField = NewValue;
MyDatabaseContext.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the object you are changing is no longer the same object as gotten from the data store.

The DataContext tracks changes to all objects it have attached. But as you never change the "source"-object as you refer it to, the data context is never notified of the change

I would suggest you to make your `ClientBO` a partial class of the `Client` instead (of course, renaming it to Client). All Linq-To-Sql classes are generated as partial and thus you can easily extend them this way

Like this:

```
public partial class Client
{
    public void GenerateInvoice()
    {
        // ... etc ...
    }
}

List<Client> clientList = MyDatabaseContext.Clients.ToList();

clientList[ someIndex ].SomeField = NewValue;
MyDatabaseContext.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: +1 Both yours and Hogan's are excellent approaches which I should have considered in the first place. I'm going with yours because it involves the least changes to my existing infrastructure.

Comment: +1 i think this is the way to go. You might want to reconsider adding "GenerateInvoice" to the Client class though:) but that is not the point here

Comment: @Pleun - GenerateInvoice() was an abstract example, and an admittedly horrible example at that.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you really want here is some extension methods:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

They will look like they are part of the class, but you implement them in a different module.  Exactly what you want.

Comment: +1 Both yours and Oskar's are appropriate. Oskar's involves fewer changes to my existing infrastructure. However I should have been considering this in the first place.